# id already registered dojo

Tags: dojo, tabcontainer, dijit.layout

I have a TabContainer, to which I m adding ContentPanels. My requirement demands that, I reload this TabContainer(which different content in ContentPanels) everytime, I click a new row on grid(generated from ajax in the same page).
Initially, when I got the problem that id is already registered, I used destroyRecursive, as seen in suggested in one of the answers here.
Now, after using that, I m getting the following result:

Result after I click on any of the row, the first time:
Just like the way, I want, with the container and the 3 content panes.

Result after I click on any of the row, the second time, and any other times:
A new container with 3 content panes is placed on top of the old one with 3 content panes.
No matter, how many rows I click, the result always has 2 containers, with new one placed above the old one.

Below is the code, I have used.

```html
    <div id = "tabsContainer">
    <div id="tabPanels" data-dojo-type = "dijit/layout/TabContainer"></div>
    </div>
```

```javascript
  function getTabPanelsForTheRow() {
        require(["dijit/layout/TabContainer",
         "dijit/layout/ContentPane"], function (TabContainer, ContentPane) {
            var tc = new TabContainer({}, "tabPanels");

            var cp1 = new ContentPane({
                title: "Contacts",
                content: "These are the activities"
            });
            tc.addChild(cp1);

            var cp2 = new ContentPane({
                title: "Activities",
                content: "These are the activities"
            });
            tc.addChild(cp2);

            var cp3 = new ContentPane({
                title: "Opportunities",
                content: "We are known for our drinks."
            });
            tc.addChild(cp3);

            tc.startup();
        });
   }

    function destroyTabPanel() {
        require(["dijit/layout/TabContainer"], function (TabContainer) {
          var tp = dijit.byId("tabPanels");
          tp.destroyRecursive(true);
    });
}
```

Everytime, I click a row, I m calling destroyTabPanel() first, and then I m calling getTabPanelsForTheRow().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like your problem is the "true" in your `destroyRecursive()` call which is instructing dojo to preserve the DOM. So you're destroying the widgets which has solved your duplicate id problem but the generated DOM is preserved; then when you call `getTabPanelsForTheRow()` it is generating 3 new panels over the existing ones.

What you want to do is, after calling `destroyRecursive()`, empty the container "tabPanel": `domConstruct.empty("tabPanel")` before calling `getTabPanelsForTheRow()`.

On a side note, you're destroying and re-instantiating your panel widget everytime you click on a row, why not store a reference to your contentPanes within your TabContainer and then write a method which destroys the contentPanes only, empty the TabContainer node and then create the new panes...

Comment: Thank you for that. I got the required result with your first suggestion. I m new to dojo, hence not able to get your second suggestion working. By the way, I tried this: 'function destroyTabPanel() {
            require(["dijit/layout/TabContainer", "dojo/dom-construct"],
        function (TabContainer) {
        var elem = dijit.byId("tabPanels");
            if(elem.hasChildren()){
                domConstruct.empty("tabPanels");
            }
        });

        }'

Comment: In the other function, instead of creating the new TabContainer, I m directly saying dijit.byId("tabPanels"), and rest is same. When, I did like this, I m able to have panels created only the first time. Rest of the times, I m having nothing displayed.

Comment: You could define your own widget which extends dijit._widgetBase, this widget would be declared on your container `div`. The widget would itself instantiate the TabContainer and panels, storing a reference to the panels in an array or object. You then instantiate this widget on page load. then change your event listener, either reference your widget directly and call a custom method "updatePanels" or something, or it could use dojo's pub/sub functionality and publish a request which the widget subscribes to. I can send an example if you like...

Comment: Thank you for the information, Laurent. It would be really helpful, if can send an example.